# the IgnorePointer is not working in the GridView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, events, gridview

```dart
class _B extends State<B>{
  ...
  // a 2*2 grid layout
  Widget _a() {
    var c = Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [_b(), _c(), _c(), _b()],
          key: ObjectKey("1"),
        ),
        width: 300,
        height: 300);
    var l = Listener(
      child: c,
      onPointerDown: (event) => print("hello"),
    );
    return l;
  }
  
  // normal widget, it's red
  Widget _b() {
    var l = Listener(
      // behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
      onPointerDown: (event) => print(0),
      child: Listener(
        onPointerDown: (event) => print(1),
        child: Listener(
          onPointerDown: (event) => print(2),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return l;
  }

  // should be ignored, it's blue
  Widget _c() {
    var l = Listener(
      // behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
      onPointerDown: (event) => print(0),
      child: Listener(
        onPointerDown: (event) => print(1),
        child: Listener(
          onPointerDown: (event) => print(2),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    var i = IgnorePointer(
      child: l,
    );
    return Listener(child: i, onPointerDown: (event) => print("3!"));
  }
}
```

- when i click the red one, here is the output. it just meets my expectations.

```
[+1052 ms] 2
[   +1 ms] 1
[        ] 0
[   +1 ms] hello
```

- But when i click the blue one, here is the output. Did't it should be ignore?How did the event be distributed to the upper widget?

```
[+2612 ms] hello
```

I have tried many methods but still not working.

here is the image, sorry for that.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBe2i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite tricky here.
It does actually ignore the events on the blue square, but you also have a listener on your whole `GridView` layout and this would be triggered always even if you create a widget that does not have a listener and add it to your `GridView`.
My proposal is removing `Listener` from your top-level layout and handling everything in your widgets or components.

```
Widget _a() {
    var c = Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [_b(), _c(), _c(), _b()],
          key: ObjectKey("1"),
        ),
        width: 300,
        height: 300);

    return c;
}
```